# Can I upgrade CPU in a Asus X550C laptop?

Tags: upgrade

This laptop comes with a Core i7 3537 processor (2.0 GHz). I want to try and get an 3.1 GHz or as close as possible to that. Is it possible?

It has a NVIDIA 720M graphics card, 1 TB hard drive and 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

[Your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/72054/Intel-Core-i7-3537U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz?q=3537) has an FCBGA1023 socket. It means it's soldered on the motherboard and you can't replace it.